# Increase item's height with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a way to create a layout without blank spaces where most items are the same dimensions, but some are 2x the height? I can make something similar to what I want with the following CSS:

Parent:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-content: flex-start;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Children:

```
width: 22%
height: 100px;
```

The tall one has `height: 200px`. It looks like this:

[image: Screnshot 1]

It's pretty close, but the problem is that I need a left-to-right order, not top-to-bottom, so I can't use `flex-direction: column`. If I do the same with `flex-direction: row`, it doesn't work:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Any ideas?

Comment: If most items are the same dimension and only a few are 2x the height, keep your `column` layout and use the `order` property to rearrange them. If this is feasible in your scenario, let me know and I'll prepare an answer with more details.

Comment: Michael_B, please do, it sounds like the best solution in my case.

Comment: `order` would be pretty gnarly with the indicated number of divs (30+)...plus it wouldn't be responsive....you'd probably need JS to keep track...and if you're using JS, you might as well use Masonry.js. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your overall scenario, you may be able to use the `order` property.

> The CSS [**`order`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property specifies the order used to lay out flex items in their flex container.

Here's a basic flexbox with 20 flex items in `column` alignment.

Numbering is vertical, like in your first image.

- Demo 1: http://jsfiddle.net/y12kh47f/

---

With `order` you can rearrange the layout without changing the HTML or [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction).

Items are stacked in columns, but the `order` property overrides their natural positioning and rearranges them into rows, like in your second image.

- Demo 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/y12kh47f/1/

---

Then, if you double the size of a few items, you just need to figure out the math for proper ordering (since each item will now occupy two spaces).

Note there is no extra vertical spacing between items.

- Demo 3: http://jsfiddle.net/y12kh47f/3/

*All flex items are set to `order: 0` by default. Negative values are permitted (i.e. `order: -3`).*

Comment: Thanks! It seems that the math would be pretty complicated and on resize I would still need to recalculate the order, so there is no real advantages over masonry.

Comment: I just came across this response and it looks like it's going to help me accomplish exactly what I need. Thank you!